# Electron how to detect if monitor/screen displays is plugged out

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, screen

i can to get screens information with: screen.getAllDisplays(),
but can not detect when active(where my app is open) display is plugging out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron have a listener to detect when a display is plugging out, is on the screen module
https://www.electronjs.org/es/docs/latest/api/screen#evento-display-removed

you could write something like this

```
const { screen } = require('electron');

screen.on('display-removed', (event, display) => {
 // do something with the display data
});
```